# remove ko suscrptions in durandal?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

Working with durandal and knockout i have some issues with suscription to the properties. Basically in my viewAttached method i have some suscription to observable properties what work very good at the first time when I load my view. In the second time when I load the view I got some issues due that code inside of suscriptions are executed (thing what i don't want).
The code is something like that:

```
export var viewAttached = function (view) {


toDate.subscribe(function (newValue) {      
    isLoading(true);
    return datacontext.getData(newValue).then(function () {
        isLoading(false);
    });
});

fromDate.subscribe(function (newValue) {       
    isLoading(true);
    return datacontext.getData(newValue).then(function () {
        isLoading(false);
    });
});
}
```

The code inside of the suscription is executed at the moment to load my view in a second time, what is wrong. I would like know if is possible remove the suscriptions to this properies aftet to unload my view. Is that possible? is possible know when a view is unload ?. any help is apreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I tried remove the suscription in Activate function (see durandal docs) but the suscription code is there yet.

```
export function activate() {      
   //remove suscriptions
    toDate.subscribe(function (newValue) {
     //do nothing
    });

    fromDate.subscribe(function (newValue) {
     //do nothing
    });   
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The fromDate and ToDate are declared as (i am using typescript)

```
export var fromDate = <any>ko.observable();
export var toDate = <any>ko.observable();
```

fromDate and toDate and seted by default on activate method:

```
function loadInitData() {   
   var focusDate = ko.observable(selectedDate);
   fromDate(firstDayOfMonth(focusDate));
   toDate(getLastDayOfMonth(focusDate));
   loadFilterLookups();
   loadRegistrations();   
}


export function activate() {      
   loadInitData();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `subscribe` isn't setup right after defining  `toDate` and `fromDate`?

Comment: the reason was because in my activate method I am calling to my service with default values for fromDate and toDate. so what i did was:
1) Set variables with default values
2) Call my services
3) Add suscriptions for futures changes in my filter from the UI.
check this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178632/how-to-avoid-run-code-twice-using-ko-property

Comment: Can you show your AMD outline, where `toDate` and `fromDate` are defined and if the module returns a singleton or a constructor function? If using a singleton do you have cacheViews: true turned on in your view?

Comment: Sadly I am using TypeScript( I say sadly because i would prefer use pur js). The way how typescript translate its code to pure js it's creating a dependency called export. so that the declarion of fromDate and toDate are:
     exports.fromDate = ko.observable();
     exports.toDate = ko.observable();

Comment: Sadly I'm not fluent enough in TypeScript ;-), so if you could add the compiled JavaScript instead. I'd like to see the JS that defines `addDate` and `fromDate` and the require `define` around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The basic solution

You asked how one can unsubscribe something subscribed to KnockoutJS.

Knockout observable subscriptions expose a [`.dispose()`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) function just for that.

When you subscribe:

```
var subscription = toDate.subscribe(function (newValue) {
 //do nothing
});
```

Clean up:

```
subscription.dispose();
```

If you want this for multiple subscriptions, you might want to consider pushing them into an array and then cleaning up after all of them, something like

```
var subs = [];
function subSafe(observable,function){
    subs.push(observable.subscribe(function));
}
function unsubscribeAll(){
    subs.forEach(function(subscription){
        subscription.dispose();
    });
}
```

---

#### A self contained example.

Let's say we have two buttons and a value, one button increments that value.
We have a listener to the value changing which has an `alert`.
When we click the second button, the subscription is removed.

**HTML:**

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.inc">Inc</button>
<button data-bind="click: $root.unsub">Remove subscription</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var vm = {
    val:ko.observable(0),
    inc:function(){
        vm.val(vm.val()+1);
    },
};
vm.sub = vm.val.subscribe(function(newVal){
   alert("Increased to "+newVal); 
});
vm.unsub = function(){
    vm.sub.dispose();    
}
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

#### [Here is a short fiddle illustrating the process](http://jsfiddle.net/n9MLY/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple - move your ViewAttached code into your Activated function - then it will only load up the first time the View is loaded.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, code for viewAttached method is executed once. The issue is that the code inside of suscription is executed every time (I could think that the properties hold or remember the suscriptions). One thing what I tried to do it's replace the suscription function with nothing in activate function (as you know activate function is executed before viewattached fucntion, according durandal documentation). see my update.

Comment: Have you got anything setting those fromDate and toDate values in a function thats running every time on load? That's the only way I can see that happening - the subcribe should only get hit when the value changes.

Comment: yes, i have it and i can't do anything about that. before to call to datacontext i have to set a default filter. I would like to have my code on this order. 
0) Remove suscriptions if they exist.
1) Set default dates
2) Add suscriptions.

Comment: Or, have a variable that's set to true on activate, set your items then and check in your subscriptions to see if that variable is false. If true, then dont run the subscription code. Then, set this variable to false when viewAttached is called so the subscriptions then work.

Comment: good try, but doesnt work. other js library  is setting the value in the markup so suscription code is runing again (after to set bool to false). so i m back to my original question, how to remove suscription code ? how i can say suscription= null?